# SMS Link to Google Maps with MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, sms, mapkit, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I wish to know if it's possible to construct an SMS to send the details of a Maps locations, which would link to at least the iOS Maps or Mobile Web Google Maps, in the same manner as that which is constructed via the actual Maps app, when the user clicks 'share' via SMS. For example see the pic:

[image]

I've scoured SO and other websites, but haven't found a definitive answer. (I'm not concerned with iOS < 5.0).

It seems that the only half decent solution is to construct the HTML link, then shorten it with Google URL shortener before appending it to the SMS message. Which I'm in the process of implementing, until I find a better solution.

Comment: I'm not on any iDevice so I can't test, but what happens when you share to a non-iOS number? Does that link only work over iMessage? Because if it's sent as an actual SMS, that means it'll have to be transcribed into a format that an SMS server will accept, and then parsed at the client. If that's just a link, for instance, that's what a non-iOS device would receive as an SMS, and you'd only have to construct such a URL and send it as an SMS for iPhone etc to parse it.

Comment: Its only useful for iOS iMessage enabled devices, but I'd still be interested in producing this functionality if possible.

Comment: Well if it's sent as an iMessage, it'll be trickier to find out exactly what is being sent (unless it's documented somewhere, I wouldn't know), but one approach would probably be to make sure that the phone is on a wireless network that you own, and sniff the data that is being sent from your phone. Tedious, but might do the job.